# Проблема со вставкой классов в eCSStractor для VS code

Tags: html, css, scss

Возможно кто-то сталкивался и работал с плагином в VS code.

Суть проблемы:

1. Копирую текст в HTML
2. Правой кнопкой мыши -> выбираю eCSStractor run
3. Пытаюсь вставить код в CSS но по факту ничего и не вставляется, словно буфер в буфере обмена ничего и нет.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 2):

В плагине используется api редактора для копирования в буфер обмена. В линукс 2 буфера обмена clipboard и primary.

находил совет установить xclip.
В терминале выполните:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xclip

У меня на Ubuntu 20.10 помогло.

Answer (score 0):

у меня также было, в настройках смотри, я вот так поменяла и заработало

[image]

Comment: К сожалению мне не помогло) максимум что, работает вариант если в Destination  указать не clipboard, который по умолчанию, а Tab, но в этом случае информация копируется и открывается в новом окне, с которого нужно еще раз копировать:).....

Answer (score 0):

Нужно задать класс

Пример: `<header class "header"><header>`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

eCSStractor, к сожалению, не идеален. Умеет определять структуру только по атрибутам классов. Например, такая структура не сработает:

```
<header>
  <nav></nav>
</header>
```

А если добавить каждому тэгу класс, то сработает:

```
<header class="header">
  <nav class="nav"></nav>
</header>
```

Результат будет следующий:

```
.header {
}
.nav {
}
```

Это крайне неправильно - задавать классы блокам, чья семантическая нагрузка и так достаточно ясна, а css могут быть заданы по названию тега. Поэтому в таких случаях расширение eCSStractor больше вредно, чем полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Так правильно, что в буфер ничего не попадает. Этот плагин компилирует HTML тэги только те где есть классы! То есть вот такое вот он НЕ скопирует:

```
<div id="main">
      <div id="main__one">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ArxhLinux та же проблема
я так понимаю разработчик плагина не учёл какие то ньюансы Линукса

максимум додумался в настройках расширения переставить на Tab
и потом ctrl+A ctrl+x ctrl+w
+2 секунды уходит